# Does "Ella piensa que es agotador, pero muy gratificante" make sense when writing a letter?

Tags: gramática, correspondencia

I am writing to my pen pal in Madrid as a way to get better at written Spanish. I am trying to tell her that my mother finds her job tiring but rewarding. Does this sentence make sense and if not could you please offer some suggestions for a rewrite?

> Ella piensa que es agotador, pero muy gratificante.

Comment: I think your translation makes sense as is.

Comment: "Le resulta agotador, pero muy gratificante."

Comment: Your sentence is good as is. In order to get better at written Spanish besides writing to your pen pal why don't you start writing your questions here in Spanish?. It would be a good practice :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think it perfectly makes sense. But maybe a bit clumsy. Here is an alternative:

> Le parece agotador, pero muy gratificante.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to say "my mother finds her job tiring but rewarding.", you could say something like you told, which is exactly what do you want to say, but there is another way to say the same but using a formal registry:

> Mi madre encuentra su trabajo cansado, pero resulta provechoso y bien remunerado.

Comment: I don't think that to change "agotador" for "cansado" is a good idea. Except possible localism I don't know, "cansado" is used with persons, not with things. "Yo estoy cansado", "ella está cansada", you do not commonly or formally say "mi trabajo es cansado" or "escribir es cansado". And "provechoso y bien remunerado" don't mean the same as "gratificante", that word is more used for more "spiritual" or "psicological" rewards, as opposed to "provechoso y bien remunerado" that implies things like a good salary. I'm not sure what of the two options would prefered the OP though.

Comment: @nox I agree on the "provechoso" part, but apart from being a less formal register "cansado" sounds fine to me. While I don't have a good overview of other dialects, "ser cansado" for "tiring" is quite common in South America.

Comment: True, I've heard "cansado" in that context being used by southamericans, but not in Spain, it sounds really strange for spaniards. By any means you don't commonly hear or read it in Spain, except possible localisms as I said.